# Does anyone make a flash diffuser for the Canon Macro Twin?

Tags: canon, flash, macro, diffusers

I'm currently looking for a flash diffuser for the Canon Macro Twin MT-24EX. I see that many people make their own. However, I'm not very good about building stuff. Is there anything available in the market? I haven't found much so far.

Comment: You don't have to 'build' much. Just cut two appropriately sized pieces out of a plastic milk bottle or other similar 'frosted' plastic and tape them onto the flash. Heck, even parchment paper for cooking will do a half decent job.

Comment: Or a tissues. I usually make diffusers for macro from tissues. Cheap, weights nothing and works wonders!

Comment: Because you're taking macro photos, and the flashes are close to the subject, I would imagine the flash heads are relatively large compared to the subject, and I'd question if you even need a diffuser.  I think you're mainly going to just scatter light away from the subject and not really improve your images.  Tissue or milk jug plastic, as desribed above should do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Stofen make a set of diffusers that fit the MT-24EX. Although they get good reviews on B&H, most photographers prefer to make their own, not because DIY is cheaper, but because DIY diffusers can provide more diffused lighting than the Stofens.

Puffer diffusers can also be used on the MT-24EX, though they don't clip in place. An elastic band will be needed to keep them on the heads (and even then they sometimes slip off).

As the others have said, it's really worth while making your own. Personally I use DIY concave diffusers or a vellum paper 'tent' diffuser.